# Почему возвращает [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ситуация, казалось, простая, но я окончательно запутался. Суть в том, что надо каждому элементу добавить id значение которого = атрибуту value. Но в конечном итоге массив valuev заполнен значениями, но когда пытаюсь их добавить, то выдаёт [object Object]. JQ:

```
var valuev = [];
        $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").each( function( index) { valuev[index] = $(this).attr("value"); });
        $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").attr({
          name: "checkMess[]",
          id: ""+($("input[type='checkbox']:not(:first)").each( function( index, element) {
            var i = index;
            $( element).attr({
              value: ""+valuev[index]// Тут [object Object]
            });
            alert(valuev[i]);//Тут нормальные значения
            }
          ))
        });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="first">
<input type="checkbox" value="second">
<input type="checkbox" value="third">
<input type="checkbox" value="fourth">
```

В результате:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="first">
<input type="checkbox" value="second" name="checkMess[]" id="[object Object]">
<input type="checkbox" value="third" name="checkMess[]" id="[object Object]">
<input type="checkbox" value="fourth" name="checkMess[]" id="[object Object]">
```

Comment: вы `id` присваиваете результат функции `each`, которым является `jqобъект`, зачем так?

Comment: @ThisMan, Результат? Я же беру значение из массива. Можете исправить потому, что я не понял

Comment: а что хотите в итоге? что бы у элементов был такой же `id` как и `value`, кроме самого первого?

Comment: @ThisMan, да. Именно так

Comment: у тебя идет запись: `id: ""+($("input[type='checkbox']:not(:first)").each(...)` - то есть свойству `id` присваивается то, что вернет метод `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно одной функцией обойтись, доп массив тут и не нужен

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").each(function() {
  $(this).attr({
    name: 'checkMess[]',
    id: $(this).attr('value'),
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="first">
<input type="checkbox" value="second">
<input type="checkbox" value="third">
<input type="checkbox" value="fourth">
```

Comment: в принципе и первый цикл не нужен с массивом, можно сразу из атрибута брать :)

Comment: @Grundy да я чего то подумал и решил, что вообще одной функцией обойтись можно)

Comment: не понял :-) я вроде про это и сказал?

Comment: @Grundy это я так с вами согласился:D

Comment: я имел ввиду вот так: `$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").attr({
  name: 'checkMess[]',
  id: function(){return this.value; }
});` :)